# Using HTML and JavaScript, how would I make a selector that would display as a UIPickerview on IOS devices?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

I am building a website which will be used mainly on iPhone's. I have a drop down menu when displaying the website on a desktop browser which is great.

First question: will it display as a UIPickerview on iPhones?
Second Question: If it doesn't display as a pickerview, what HTML and JavaScript code do i need to use to make it work.

Here is my current code.

```
        <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
           <option>Please select</option>
              <option value="arts_crafts.html">Arts & Crafts</option>
              <option value="">Education & Training</option>
              <option value="">Markets</option>

              <option value="">Coffee & Cake</option>
              <option value="">Deli’s and Baking</option>
              <option value="">Gift Shops</option>

              <option value="">Record store</option>
              <option value="">Clothing and Shoes</option>
              <option value="">Health and Beauty</option>

              <option value="">Kids</option>
              <option value="">Parks</option>
              <option value="">Churches</option>

              <option value="pubsbarsgig.html">Pubs/Venues/Gigs</option>
              <option value="">Family activities</option>
              <option value="">Stay in Stroud</option>

              <option value="">Eat in Stroud</option>
              <option value="">Charity Shops</option>
              <option value="">Estate Agents</option>
        </select>​
```

will this code display as a UIPickerview on an IOS device  or do i need to change it?

Answer (score 1):

It will display as a UIPickerView, you don't need to change anything.
And I think this question was actually unnecessary, you could have just tested the code.
Here you can see the test, just open it on an iPhone 
[JSFiddle Test](https://jsfiddle.net/h0m8zegx/)
With your own code

```
   <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
       <option>Please select</option>
          <option value="arts_crafts.html">Arts & Crafts</option>
          <option value="">Education & Training</option>
          <option value="">Markets</option>

          <option value="">Coffee & Cake</option>
          <option value="">Deli’s and Baking</option>
          <option value="">Gift Shops</option>

          <option value="">Record store</option>
          <option value="">Clothing and Shoes</option>
          <option value="">Health and Beauty</option>

          <option value="">Kids</option>
          <option value="">Parks</option>
          <option value="">Churches</option>

          <option value="pubsbarsgig.html">Pubs/Venues/Gigs</option>
          <option value="">Family activities</option>
          <option value="">Stay in Stroud</option>

          <option value="">Eat in Stroud</option>
          <option value="">Charity Shops</option>
          <option value="">Estate Agents</option>
    </select>​
```